# retryWhen is not resubscribing source as expected

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm writing logic for checking status of an object every t seconds until it's completed. I decided to use `retryWhen` operator.

```
getObjectStatus(someObject: someObjectInstance)
    .flatMap { someObject -> Observable<SomeObject> in
        if someObject.status == .notProcessed {
            return .error(SomeObjectNotProcessed())
        } else {
            return .just(someObject)
        }
    }
    .retryWhen { errors -> Observable<Void> in
        let retry = errors.enumerated().flatMap { retryCount, error -> Observable<Void> in
            guard retryCount < statusRequestCount else {
                print("The maximum number of request has been reached.")
                return .error(error)
            }

            if error is SomeObjectNotProcessed {
                return Observable.just(Void())
                        .delay(statusRequestDelay, scheduler: BackgroundScheduler.instance)
            } else {
                return .error(error)
            }
        }

        return retry
    }
    .subscribeOn(BackgroundScheduler.instance)
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] someObject in
        self?.someObjectProcessingSucceeded()
    }, onError: { [weak self] error in
        self?.someObjectProcessingFailed(error: error)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Where the `getObjectStatus` method create request to the server.

Now the problem is that with this code every t seconds (`statusRequestDelay` actually) I'm not making a request to the server. Every t seconds it returns the same instance of `someObject`. If I replace `getObjectStatus` with:

```
Observable.just(Void())
    .flatMap { _ in self.getObjectStatus(someObject: someObjectInstance) }
```

it works perfectly, which means that it makes server request every t seconds. It looks like the first, original `Observable` is not repeating.

Comment: What is the type that getObjectStatus() returns? Your first closure doesn't make a lot of sense to me at it stands...

Comment: You can see based on following `flatMap` operator, that it returns an `Observable<SomeObject>`.

Comment: So not a Single or some other type that implements flatMap... I would have just used map there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how your `getObjectStatus` function is written. Apparently, it returns a `.just` or some other observable that doesn't actually retry the network call. Without seeing that code I can't give a definitive answer.

However notice this:

```
func getObjectStatus(someObject: Int) -> Observable<SomeObject> {
    var count = 0
    return Observable.create { observer in
        print("called getObjectStatus")
        if count < 3 {
            observer.onNext(SomeObject(status: .notProcessed))
            observer.onCompleted()
            count += 1
        }
        else {
            observer.onNext(SomeObject(status: .processed))
            observer.onCompleted()
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Using the above with your chain will cause "called getObjectStatus" to print 3 times.

While:

```
var count = 0
func getObjectStatus(someObject: Int) -> Observable<SomeObject> {
    print("called getObjectStatus")
    if count < 3 {
        count += 1
        return Observable.just(SomeObject(status: .notProcessed))
    }
    else {
        return Observable.just(SomeObject(status: .processed))
    }
}
```

Will not.

The difference here is that in the latter case, the `.just(SomeObject(status: .notProcessed))` is what is being resubscribed to, so it returns the same thing every time.

Burying the call in a flatMap works because it's the `.just(Void())` that is getting resubscribed to which means the contents of the flatMap is called again.